# Баг в Unity при установке Unity Ads

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Появилась проблема при установке *Unity Ads* в проект. Настроил *Unity DashBoard* ещё.
Вот сами проблемы:

**1.** *Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@3.6.1\Runtime\Monetization\AndroidPlacementContentOperations.cs(101,41): error CS0433: The type 'IUnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

**2.**
*Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@3.6.1\Runtime\Monetization\AndroidPlacementContentOperations.cs(54,17): error CS0433: The type 'IUnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

**3.** *Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@3.6.1\Runtime\Monetization\AndroidPlacementContentOperations.cs(55,40): error CS0433: The type 'IUnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

**4.** *Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@3.6.1\Runtime\Monetization\AndroidPlacementContentOperations.cs(63,21): error CS0433: The type 'IUnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

**5.** *Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@3.6.1\Runtime\Monetization\AndroidPlacementContentOperations.cs(64,42): error CS0433: The type 'IUnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

**6.** *Library\PackageCache\com.unity.ads@3.6.1\Runtime\Monetization\MonetizationPlatform.cs(33,17): error CS0433: The type 'UnityLifecycleManager' exists in both 'UnityEngine.Advertisements.Editor, Version=3.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'UnityEngine.Advertisements, Version=3.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'*

Что делать с этим? У кого-нибудь есть опыт с этим?

Comment: Ты установил UnityAds через AssetStore и Monetization через PackageManager и у тебя появилась эта ерунда. Была такая же проблема, я какие-то файлы удалил и не было этой ошибки, но там и не билдился проект... Кароче сноси свой проект и закачивай что-то одно. Я не знаю что еще можно подсказать

Comment: Но если я удалю из своего проекта эту рекламу, она не будет работать, можно ли как-то это ошибку исправить, не удаляя файлы?

Comment: Использовать один из вариантов. Какой лучше? Наверно через PackageManager устанавливать Monetization. Это все что я знаю